# How to draw a star in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

i this my code this way but is not coming out the right way. I don't know what i missing, i can't figure out. if some want want to help!!

```
private var _color:uint;
private var _radius:int;

public function Star(c:uint = 0xff0000, r:int = 15)
{
  _color = c;
  _radius = r;

  createStar();

}       
    private function createStar():void      
    {           
      this.graphics.lineStyle(3,_color);
      this.graphics.moveTo(_radius,0);

      for(var i:int = 1; i < 11; i++)
      {
        var radius2:Number = _radius;

        if (i % 2 > 0)
      }
      _radius = _radius/2;
      var angle:Number = (6.28 / 5) * i;
      this.graphics.lineTo(Math.cos(angle) * radius2, Math.sin(angle) * radius2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your createStar() function looks pretty bad:

- unfinished conditional (`if (i % 2 > 0)`) which is a syntax error
- hardcoded value: `var angle:Number = (6.28 / 5) * i;`, maybe not that bad assuming 6.28 is supposed to be Math.PI * 2, but the `i` counter doesn't belong there
- drawing a single line (`this.graphics.lineTo(Math.cos(angle) * radius2, Math.sin(angle) * radius2);`) and expecting a star

you might want to try something like this:

```
private function createStar():void      
{           
    graphics.lineStyle(3,_color);
    graphics.moveTo(_radius,0);

    var angleIncrement = Math.PI / 5;//5 pointed star -> 10 point arround the circle (360 degrees or Math.PI * 2): 5 outer points, 5 inner points
    var ninety:Number = Math.PI * .5;//offset the rotation by 90 degrees so the star points up

    for(var i:int = 0; i <= 10; i++){//for each point
        var radius:Number = (i % 2 > 0 ? _radius : _radius * .5);//determine if the point is inner (half radius) or outer(full radius)
        var px:Number = Math.cos(ninety + angleIncrement * i) * radius;//compute x
        var py:Number = Math.sin(ninety + angleIncrement * i) * radius;//and y using polar to cartesian coordinate conversion
        if(i == 0) graphics.moveTo(px,py);//move the 'pen' so we don't draw lines from (0,0)
        graphics.lineTo(px,py);//draw each point of the star
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this blog post](http://www.funky-monkey.nl/blog/2010/04/20/drawing-shapes-in-as3-a-class-to-draw-an-arc-star-gear-cog-wedge-and-a-burst/)

or at the code of the class in here: http://pastie.org/929979#265

look for the `drawStar` function in there

(I didn't copy the source because I didn't ask the author for)